# Why load() works in the same way that get() in Hibernate?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I'm trying to update a entity field in this way:

```
    SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    User user = session.load(User.class, 4);
    user.setName("Bober11");
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
```

I was thinking that in this case Hibernate will update the row in the table without hitting it (I mean, without select), however, I saw in the console that Hibernate is doing a select:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_1_0_, user0_.email as email2_1_0_, user0_.name as name3_1_0_, user0_.phone as phone4_1_0_ from User user0_ where user0_.id=?
Hibernate: update User set email=?, name=?, phone=? where id=?
```

I.e. it looks like if I was using get().

Why this's happening? Is it possible to update and insert without selecting? and without using direct sql query statements.

Comment: I just realized, that Hibernate is doing the "select" statement when I set the name field (user.setName("Bober11")). I suppose that's the expected behavior for load(). In the case of get() the select occurs inmediately after get(). I'd still like to know if there's a way to update an entity in the table without doing a select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do call `session.load(User.class, 4)` hibernate creates proxy object for User object without db call (without select) and connect id = 4 to proxy object. It's just proxy with ID and information about session , object type , id ...
Real coll to db happens only when you call proxy methods - it's load / select query that load real object from DB. In your case you call `setName("Bober11")` on proxy object , and as result you see select query.

If you need update user info by id without extra hibernate select do it with HQL update query :

```
    String updateUserHql = "update User set name = :newName where id= :userId";
    Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
    query.setLong("userId",userId); // userID= 4
    query.setLong("newName ",newUserName);//Bober11
    query.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: The query provided in this answer is a SQL query. The question asks for a way to update through Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

`load()` returns a proxy object without hitting the database. only when you change its field the object is selected from the database.

`get()` returns the actual object and thus always hits the database.
If you wish to update the table without any select you will have to create an HQL query as follows:

```
session.createQuery("UPDATE MY_TABLE SET MY_FIELD = 'MY_VALUE'").executeUpdate();
```